# Unity Game performance when running 2 instances on same machine

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm developing a Unity multiplayer game where a player can either be the host or the client.

While testing, I needed to run 2 instances on my development machine for the sake of testing and development. the 2 instances are either a build and the editor or 2 builds.

I'm working on a windows machine.

whichever build has windows focus, runs at 200 FPS. The other instance is very sluggish. This is not a problem with machine resources as the machine has 64 GB of RAM and an RTX 2080 GPU.

The strange thing that I have tried and worked is that if both instances are running and a third application has the focus (say notepad or task manager), both games run at around 120 FPS without any issues.

I thought to develop an application that takes focus from both of them and run transparent in the foreground but I felt that this is a very bad solution and there must be a good one out there.

Is there an option or a setting to cap performance per instance so the other can work normally? or an option that can force both instances to go out of focus without using a third app?

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: You could set [Application.runInBackground](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html) to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Application.targetFrameRate to 60.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm and I can run both of them now side by side.